# ¿Pasar datos entre Activtiys usando la base de datos (Sqlite)?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

tengo una duda de como pasar información entre activitys usando la base de datos, ya que he visto muchos tutoriales de como hacerlo,pero siempre los hacen con una llave tecleada y yo uso una 
autoincrementable y no se como usarlo para pasar los datos y se mantenga 
el contexto sobre esa misma tabla durante el uso de la aplicacion.

Aqui dejo el codigo de cuando registro algo y paso a la otra activity:

Intent irTrabajo = new Intent(dialog.getContext(), menu_trabajo_Activity.class);

```
            //acceso a la base de datos
            ConexionBaseDatos conexion = new ConexionBaseDatos(dialog.getContext(), "bd_uno", null, 1);

            final String Nombre = editNombre.getText().toString();
            final String Tipo = ediTipo.getText().toString();
            //abro el modo escritura
            SQLiteDatabase db = conexion.getWritableDatabase();

            //metodo para agregar los valores
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ConstantesDatos.Nombre, Nombre);
            values.put(ConstantesDatos.Tipo, Tipo);

            //insertar valores a la base de datos
            long EnvioLibro = db.insert(ConstantesDatos.Tabla_Nombres, null, values);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Se agrego con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //cerrar la base de datos
            db.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una clase que se llame utilidades o como guste, dentro de ello crea las variables que quieres usar durante la ejecucion de la aplicacion, por ejemplo:

```
class Utilidades{
 public static String Nombre;
 public static String Tipo;
}
```

en donde tu creas el ContentValues para asignar las variables para la insersion en la base de datos agrega:

```
Utilidades.Nombre=Nombre;
Utilidades.Tipo=Tipo;
```

y en la activity o en donde tu lo quieras recuperar el dato le llamas a la clase que contien las variales estaticas.

```
Log.i("LOG",Utilidades.Nombre);
```

Esto es recomendable solo cuando se use pocas variables ya que si son varias va utilizar mas recursos del movil